# Trigger HTML event by scrolling past a certain point, and then retrigger by scrolling back

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, point

I want to trigger the fade once I scroll past a point, but then fade back in once I scroll back.
Am I on the right track? I don't see why it isn't working. So far it seems to fade out at an arbitrary point and then never fade in again.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
                $( "h1" ).fadeTo( "slow", ".05" );
            }
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() <= 20){
                $( "h1" ).fadeTo( "slow", "1" );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var flag = $(window).scrollTop() > 20 ? 1 : 2;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 20 && flag != 1) {
            $("h1").fadeTo("slow", ".05");
            flag = 1;
            console.log('t1')
        } else if (scrollTop <= 20 && flag != 2) {
            $("h1").fadeTo("slow", "1");
            flag = 2;
            console.log('t2')
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
          if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
              $( "h1" ).fadeTo( "slow", ".05" );
          }
          else if($(window).scrollTop() <= 20){
              $( "h1" ).fadeTo( "slow", "1" );
          }
      });
});
```